# Autorefresh DIV, No PHP

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to autorefresh a div on this page: http://americanart.si.edu/index_newsplash3r.cfm ("Places to Explore" area). Right now we have 3 different images and text that arbitrarily display when you reload the page. I'd like these elements to change automatically, without reloading the page.

The page is done in Coldfusion 9. Most AJAX autorefresh code assumes you're using PHP.

Does anyone have a link to code I could use to do this without PHP? I don't think it's necessary that it be Coldfusion code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup an Ajax call to the server side to get the photo path and the text.
Something like this.

```
    $(function(){
        function FillDivAtRandom(current){
        setTimeout(function(){

            //pass the current place to explore id to the server so you don't get the same back, if none then return anyone.

            $.post("http://americanart.si.edu/Request/PlacesToExploreNext", current, function(data){

//fill the div with new data return from server
//you don't seem to have an ID on that div or elements so put one on it first then use it as a selector 

                //set the image
                $('#placestoexplore_image').attr('src', data.image);
                //set the text
                $('#placestoexplore_description').html(data.description);
            });

            //call the function again
            FillDivAtRandom(current);

        }, 10000);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Let me try that out. Thx. I'll let you know how it turns out.

Comment: A couple questions blackops: what is this URL supposed to be:        `//pass the current place to explore id to the server so you don't get the same back, if none then return anyone.

            $.post("http://americanart.si.edu/Request/PlacesToExploreNext", current, function(data){` Also, I do have a class on that Div but I can change it to an id.

Comment: The url is a server side file that will get the variable from the HTTP post, then return a json object with the image source and the description.

Comment: Let it be known that I do not know ColdFusion but this is how I would do it in PHP and .Net